# How to enumerate memory used and reserved by kernel and drivers

Tags: memory

I am running two VMs (Ubuntu 18.04), both with 0.5 GiB of memory. One is on AWS and one is on Azure. I found that despite both systems having 512 MiB of memory, the AWS system has 479 MiB of usable memory:

```
~$ free --mebi
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            479         131          17           1         330         334
Swap:             0           0           0
```

and the Azure system only has 392 MiB:

```
~$ free --mebi
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            392         289          28           2          74          89
Swap:             0           0           0
```

The biggest difference I can see between these two systems is that the Azure system reserves far more memory at boot:

AWS:

```
~$ dmesg | grep "Memory"
[    0.000000] Memory: 467376K/523892K available (12300K kernel code, 2394K rwdata, 3924K rodata, 2376K init, 2376K bss, 56516K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
```

Azure:

```
~$ dmesg | grep "Memory"
[    0.000000] Memory: 376860K/523832K available (14348K kernel code, 2578K rwdata, 4252K rodata, 2320K init, 2296K bss, 146972K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
```

Is there a way I can enumerate the memory used and reserved by each driver, kernel module, and the kernel itself? Or more broadly, does anyone know exactly why the Azure VM uses more memory?

Comment: I think you could search "linux memory usage". /proc is a good place to look for

Comment: If you look in `dmesg` more (grep for `reserved`) it should tell you the ranges that are being reserved. Most will probably be BIOS-e820, meaning the virtual-BIOS marked it to be reserved. Is it possible you're using some of it a video RAM? (No experience with HyperV)

Comment: I *think* the "reserved" figure in the Memory line included the initrd.  That would mean if you want a more accurate/meaningul figure at the time of the Memory line, you have to subtract the number from the line "Freeing initrd memory: xxxxxxK" (if present).  In another case than this, it was necessary to look through `dmesg` quite carefully.  There wasn't another indicator, as far as I could tell. Can I suggest creating a github account and publishing both `dmesg`s on gist.github.com?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70043/offer-a-stack-exchange-brand-pastebin/70050#70050

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/520065/82mb-of-reserved-memory-on-512mb-x86-system/520525#520525