# Reserved RAM: Determine the reason for reserved main memory?

Tags: linux-kernel, ram

On a server, the linux kernel at boot informs about the RAM setup. It indicates that of the physical 512GiB RAM (536409480kiB), only roughly 503GiB RAM (527942676kiB) are available.

```
root@ada:~# dmesg | grep Memory:
[    5.891484] Memory: 527942676K/536409480K available (10252K kernel code, 1241K rwdata, 3320K rodata, 1592K init, 2272K bss, 8466804K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
```

Some memory being unavailable is expected given the IO regions reserved by the bios.

```
root@ada:~# dmesg | grep reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009c000-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000004f66f000-0x0000000057677fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006cdcf000-0x000000006efcefff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000070000000-0x000000008fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e0000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000107f380000-0x000000107fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000207ff80000-0x000000207fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000307ff80000-0x000000307fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000407ff80000-0x000000407fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000507ff80000-0x000000507fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000607ff80000-0x000000607fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000707ff80000-0x000000707fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000807ff80000-0x000000807fffffff] reserved
```

which however do not amount to more than 100MiB.

I wonder how to investigate what causes this memory to be reserved? What is the cause?

Without understanding the purpose for the reserved memory it seems simply like a ~9GiB loss of memory.
Given that the system acts as a virtualization host, this "loss" is excarbated as each virtualized guest system in turn has a similar fraction of its dedicated RAM also "reserved".

Since [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/520065/82mb-of-reserved-memory-on-512mb-x86-system) have suggested that such memory could be reserved for "shared memory" of a graphic card, I looked this up, yet the adapter present only seems to use ~50MiB at most.

```
root@ada:~# lspci  | grep -i vga
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. Integrated Matrox G200eW3 Graphics Controller (rev 04)
root@ada:~# lspci -s 03:00.0 -vvv
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. Integrated Matrox G200eW3 Graphics Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0 (4000ns min, 8000ns max)
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 243
        NUMA node: 0
        Region 0: Memory at eb000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Region 1: Memory at f9808000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Region 2: Memory at f9000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8M]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Kernel driver in use: mgag200
        Kernel modules: mgag200
```

**Update**

[Here](https://pastebin.com/gWK0cmzd) is the complete dmesg output

**Update**
It is a Dell Poweredge Server, that boots in BIOS mode (not UEFI)

**Update**

Here is the output of [`/proc/iomem`](https://pastebin.com/nKn4tt0w)

**Update**

Here the evaluated output of `/proc/iomem`

```
root@ada:~# cat /proc/iomem | tr [a-z] [A-Z] | while IFS='-: ' read AD1 AD2 REST;
> do echo "$(( $(echo "obase=10; ibase=16; ( $AD2 - $AD1 ) " | bc) >> 20))MB for  $REST" ; 
> done | sort -h  

[...]
14MB for  ACPI NON-VOLATILE STORAGE                                                                                                        
15MB for  0000:03:00.0
15MB for  MGADRMFB_VRAM
15MB for  PCI BUS 0000:02
15MB for  PCI BUS 0000:03
33MB for  RESERVED
128MB for  RESERVED
207MB for  PCI BUS 0000:20
207MB for  PCI BUS 0000:40
207MB for  PCI BUS 0000:60
207MB for  PCI BUS 0000:80
207MB for  PCI BUS 0000:A0
207MB for  PCI BUS 0000:C0
207MB for  PCI BUS 0000:E0
255MB for  PCI MMCONFIG 0000 [BUS 00-FF]
255MB for  PNP 00:00
315MB for  PCI BUS 0000:00
343MB for  SYSTEM RAM
511MB for  RESERVED
543MB for  RESERVED
1269MB for  SYSTEM RAM
63475MB for  SYSTEM RAM
65535MB for  SYSTEM RAM
65535MB for  SYSTEM RAM
65535MB for  SYSTEM RAM
65535MB for  SYSTEM RAM
65535MB for  SYSTEM RAM
65535MB for  SYSTEM RAM
65535MB for  SYSTEM RAM
915967MB for  PCI BUS 0000:00
915967MB for  PCI BUS 0000:20
915967MB for  PCI BUS 0000:40
915967MB for  PCI BUS 0000:60
915967MB for  PCI BUS 0000:80
915967MB for  PCI BUS 0000:A0
915967MB for  PCI BUS 0000:C0
915967MB for  PCI BUS 0000:E0
```

The output of dmidecode on the system is (since I expect that to be fitting in the context of RAM availability):

```
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2 present.
81 structures occupying 6778 bytes.
Table at 0x6E8AD000.

Handle 0xDA00, DMI type 218, 11 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                DA 0B 00 DA B2 00 17 20 0E 10 03

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 26 bytes
BIOS Information
        Vendor: Dell Inc.
        Version: 1.14.3
        Release Date: 07/17/2020
        Address: 0xF0000
        Runtime Size: 64 kB
        ROM Size: 0 MB
        Characteristics:
                ISA is supported
                PCI is supported
                PNP is supported
                BIOS is upgradeable
                BIOS shadowing is allowed
                Boot from CD is supported
                Selectable boot is supported
                EDD is supported
                Japanese floppy for Toshiba 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
                5.25"/360 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
                Serial services are supported (int 14h)
                CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
                ACPI is supported
                USB legacy is supported
                BIOS boot specification is supported
                Function key-initiated network boot is supported
                Targeted content distribution is supported
                UEFI is supported
            BIOS Revision: 1.14
    
    Handle 0x0100, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
    System Information
            Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
            Product Name: PowerEdge R7425
            Version: Not Specified
            Serial Number: XXXXXX
            UUID: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-4a10-8048-c3c04f593533
            Wake-up Type: Power Switch
            SKU Number: SKU=NotProvided;ModelName=PowerEdge R7425
        Family: PowerEdge
```

The complete dmidecode with possible information regarding the mysterious unavailability of roughly 9GiB of RAM can be seen here https://pastebin.com/nHYyuH7h

[image]

Comment: Can you post your `dmesg`?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, sure I can , it is however very long, would that be appropriate to put it into the question (as it would become instantly very very long) ?

Comment: You could use pastebin.com. :-) And please set expiration just in case. Maybe you have some data in it you don't want to remain public forever.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thank you for the pastebin.com suggestion and also for the heads-up with private data in the dmesg output (gotta figure out what parts of dmesg are better removed before posting).

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but all those reserved spaces above add up to around 1.2Gbyte by my calculations ... still far less than 8Gbyte, but an order of magnitude bigger than 100Mbyte

Comment: @MurrayJensen you meant the bios-e820 reserved areas?

Comment: Yes - no idea what they are, I just added the region sizes up

Comment: Please upload `/proc/iomem` and the output of `https://github.com/madrisan/linux-iomem/blob/master/iomem.sh`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I have updated the answer to include a pastebin of `/proc/iomem` . I will check out the github shell script and I thnk you for the suggestion to include those uploads!. Thank you

Comment: I'm quite confused with `915967MB for  PCI BUS 0000:00
915967MB for  PCI BUS 0000:20
915967MB for  PCI BUS 0000:40
915967MB for  PCI BUS 0000:60
915967MB for  PCI BUS 0000:80
915967MB for  PCI BUS 0000:A0
915967MB for  PCI BUS 0000:C0
915967MB for  PCI BUS 0000:E0`

Maybe this is where your RAM has gone. We need some hardcore kernel hackers.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov. You are right. I am a little confused too. The good thing is that the virtualized guest systems are showing siminalr amount of reserved RAM, so I guess its possible for me to setup a whole test set of different configs (sorta fuzzing) to find one that reduces reserved memory. It seems not normal. The `915967MB`  memory from `/proc/iomem` might yet just be the rages reserved. Also I guess it is DELL hardware so one might expect buggy bios/uefi there too... I shall later on use my personal unix.se account to set a bounty here.Thank you

Comment: Firstly, when subtracting start and end addresses to get the size of a range, you need to add 1. Secondly, when you add up all the SYSTEM RAM spaces, it comes (very close) to 512Gbyte. The `/proc/iomem` output is showing you the physical address space mappings for the hardware in the memory controller. The spaces labelled SYSTEM RAM are where the ram resides in the physical address space. These will be divided up into pages and mapped into the virtual address space of processes, including the virtual address space of the kernel.

Comment: While it’s certainly an interesting question, I don’t think it has much to do with Linux as such. The reason those memory ranges are reserved lies somewhere within your machine’s firmware; I assume any other operating system would reserve the same ranges.

Comment: I don't see why memory mapped IO should reduce available RAM, unless physical ram approaches maximum physical address space (E.g. 32bit OS with 4GB of RAM).

Comment: I wonder if it could be GPU mapped memory.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Good idea, But it is **not GPU mapped**. `lspci -vvv | grep -i 'VGA ' -A 10 | grep Memory` yields 3 regions : `Region 0: Memory at eb000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=16M]` , `Region 1: Memory at f9808000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]` , `Region 2: Memory at f9000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8M]` . The server system does not have a "fancy" graphic adapter, just a integrated bare minimum vga thing for setup puposes.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot or take a picture of your memory you have in the server. You could have a non standard or incorrect memory configuration.
This would explain all the channels being used for other purposes. As those memory channels would be reserved. Also whats the model of the PE server in question. Thanks.

Comment: I would readily provide a screenshot, or even a picture. What is the command and its output you would recomment the screenshot to be taken of? Or should you mean that a picture of  physical ram bars should be provided?

Comment: It is a **DELL Poweredge R7425** Server with 512GB memory.

Comment: You'll have to do some legwork here. It will be easier if you slide off the cover and take a picture. But pay close attention to page 113 in your Dell EMC PowerEdge R7425 Installation and Service Manual. Optional Go into your DRAC and it should list your dimm locations. Then read another page down or two in the manual. Most people find out that they accidentally fill a slot they shouldn't have. And the bios never picks up the error.  Do you have one processor or two. That also makes a difference.

Comment: I have requested the local admin to provided the information / pictures. As soon as they are there I will post. Hope this is not invain and an unavailability of 9 of 512 GB RAM is a normal thing.

Comment: Here is my output for my server. # dmesg | grep Memory:
[    5.229391] Memory: 396051868K/402524300K available (14339K kernel code, 2379K rwdata, 4928K rodata, 2704K init, 5020K bss, 6472432K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)327MB for  RESERVED
476MB for  SYSTEM RAM
831MB for  PCI BUS 0000:80
895MB for  PCI BUS 0000:00
1445MB for  SYSTEM RAM
131071MB for  PCI BUS 0000:00
131071MB for  PCI BUS 0000:80
391167MB for  SYSTEM RAM

Comment: Thanks for giving a comparison with your memory values. If I interpret this correctly you have `402524300K` ( `= 383.8 GiB` ) of main memory, from which only 396051868K ( `= 377.7 GiB` ) is available. About 1.6% of memory was then not available. I cannot understand how this could be correct easily. Most of the the fact that the number of GiB of physical memory given is not a integer seems strange. Have you any more insights here (is this a physical or a virtual machine?). OK, the `536409480K` as in the `dmesg` of my `512GiB` machine is also a strange `511.5599... GiB` not integer number

Comment: I know its hard to wrap your head around. But in the real world of memory. Everything is lower. "Kind of like drive space is." You have a 128GB drive but you only use 118GB. It's basically the same way once coincide. You have memory ranges eating up dimm channels. Video USB pci devices. The more memory the bigger lose.

Comment: I am used to the "honesty of advertisment". The bigger issue is that I want to know where this memory goes to. The unavailable memory (some 9GiB or 512GiB) has - in contrast to a number cheatery that is happening at hard-disk sizes - been there at the beginning.

Comment: Note it is only integrated graphics that will use the main RAM. That is what the integration is. The other type uses separate memory.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor dedicated graphics had separate dedicated RAM true. However the unavailable `9GiB` here do not seem to be aloted to the a graphic adapter here as lspci does show put one adapter and that uses only `~24MB` .

Answer (score 5):

I think I know the answer (not 100% sure though).

Linux has `struct page` structure associated with memory pages. Size of this structure varies between architectures, on 32-bit x86 Linux it's 40 bytes, on 64-bit, I beleive, due to bigger pointer sizes, it's 64 bytes.

You can find it here:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1/source/include/linux/mm_types.h

Those structures could be organized in different ways (see https://lwn.net/Articles/789304/), but ultimately, every memory page on your system gets one such structure.

That means that kernel needs to reserve 64 bytes for each 4096 bytes (page size) And that means, for 512G it will reserve ((512×1024³)/4096)×64 = 8589934592 bytes, or 8388608K, or 8G exactly.

Add this to the code, ro/rwdata, init, bss sections, and you get 8407285K, really close to 8466804K we are trying to explain here.

You can also boot your server with, say, `mem=256G` kernel parameter. This will limit the available memory size to 256G, and you will find out that the reserved size shrunk nearly by the factor of 2. That also speaks for the theory above, and, unfortunately, given how well the information is packed within this structure and how essential it is, I don't think there is a way to make this memory available for other uses.

Comment: Using hugepages (there are 2M and 1G variants) might be able to reduce your page table overhead.  QEMU (and likely the other major virtualization systems on linux) can take advantage of hugepages--on the host side.  On the guest side, you can try to get the guest apps to use hugepages as well.  Note that when running a VM, you pay the page table overhead twice, so even using it only on the host side will be a benefit.  See `-mem-path` for QEMU