# Why Linux kernel reserve ~4GiB out of 256GiB memory and how to free it

Tags: linux-kernel, memory

I have 256GiB installed memory in my server but when i use the free command, the available memory is only 250GiB. When looking at the dmesg logs, I found that the kernel is reserving 4331284KiB of memory.

```
Memory: 1895680K/267031708K available (12295K kernel code, 2536K rwdata, 7568K rodata, 2424K init, 3680K bss, 4331284K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
```

So far i have found 874MiB/4230MiB

- ~650MiB from [iomem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617160/reserved-ram-determine-the-reason-for-reserved-main-memory)
- 88MiB from sysctl vm.min_free_kbytes
- 136MiB from admin and user reserved memory

Note: I am using 10 GPUs in my server which uses 3040MiB (non-prefetchable and prefetchable). But i am not sure if this memory is reserved from the main memory

- Does anyone know where can i locate the rest of the memory?
- Also, if possible, how can i free some part of this reserved memory?

Comment: A very quick search on google brought up this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66299455/11422727

Comment: @ARF thanks for the response. But i am not sure if i wanted to reduce this memory since this can break the system.

Comment: What did you mean by "how to free it" if not to lower the reserve?

Comment: So there is 4GiB reserved memory by the kernel and by freeing i meant lowering this reserve memory to maybe 2GiB or 3GiB